# HTML5 Character Animation

Tags: html, css

Is it possible, in html5 (with the use of js and css3) to have Sprite/Character hover on the bottom corner of the page (like the Microsoft Clippy did in Office), and have it say stuff?

By say stuff I mean have little text bubbles load dynamically.

Comment: Actually, you can make such an animation with ActiveX, but this will be available only on WinXP. In the next version, like Vista and 7, it is removed I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but as Clippy it will be rather annoying. Canvas is a good choice to for such a thing, like in this [small canvas game](http://www.pluginmedia.net/dev/infector/).

Answer (score 0):

SVG might be a good option as well if you want to design character as discrete visual elements that can be animated.